# How can I guess the last time a repository was fetched/pulled from a remote?

Tags: git, bash

I have a few dumb bash scripts in a git repository used by a few others.  These are run on clients I can't control, but I'd like to encourage the users to keep them up-to-date, without forcing the user to connect to a remote every time.

Bash pseudo code would be something like this:

```
if [[ thirty_days_ago < date_of_last_fetch ]] then;
   echo "Warning, these scripts are more than 30 days old.  You should try a git pull"
fi
```

I've done some searching, but haven't figured out a command that can be run or a file whose mtime can be read to indicate the last time a user checked the remote. I prefer if this is an option it'll be available per-remote, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: Might be a big hard in a bash script, but `git log` will show the time of commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the file

```
.git/refs/remotes/remotename/branchname
```

gets updated every time you fetch the branch. Check for its mtime.

if you want to check if the remote branch has been merged in the local branch you can check if the refs of "remotename/branchname" and "branchname" are equal:

```
getref='git log --format="%H" -n 1'
if [ `$getref remotename/branchname` != `$getref branchname` ] ; then
    echo "the local branch and the remote branch diverged! Please pull!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to have a script to perform the fetch/pull for them and record the time in a file in the `.git` directory manually.

You could also use the time of the last upstream commit as a rough gauge.

```
if [ "$(git log -1 --format=%ct origin/master)" -lt "$(date -d'30 days ago' +%s)" ]; then
    echo 'Warning....'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined a few solutions that use `stat [OS dependent flags] .git/FETCH_HEAD` to get the `modified time` of that file in the linked answer below.

It updates every time a fetch happens regardless if there was anything fetched

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54264210/622276

This snippet is part of a [bash prompt git integration](https://github.com/neozenith/dotfiles#git-bash-prompt) I maintain for myself, but feel free to pilfer snippets.

```sh
# No repo == no more work 
local REPO_ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null`
if [[ -n $REPO_ROOT && -e "$REPO_ROOT/.git/FETCH_HEAD" ]]; then

    case $OSTYPE in
      darwin*)
        local LAST_FETCH="$(stat -f '%m' $REPO_ROOT/.git/FETCH_HEAD)" 
        local FETCH_THRESHOLD="$(date -v-15m +%s)"  
      ;;
      *)
        local LAST_FETCH="$(stat -c %Y $REPO_ROOT/.git/FETCH_HEAD)" 
        local FETCH_THRESHOLD="$(date -d'15 minutes ago' +%s)"  
      ;;
    esac

    # Fork fetch process in background
    if [[ $LAST_FETCH -lt $FETCH_THRESHOLD ]]; then
      git fetch --all --quiet --prune 2> /dev/null &
    fi

fi
```