# how to see the last three time stamps that I did git pull?

Tags: git, macos, github, command-line, bitbucket

I found there is only way to see the last git pull, which is the most current one I already done, I want to know the one that I did prior to the one I did most recently. Because I want to reverse my repo to that specific version at the date when I pulled it and the most recent pull I did is messed up.
So in summary, the timestamp of the one **BEFORE my latest** git pull is what I need.

The repo is bitbucket based git repo.

Is there way to do that at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git reflog --date=iso

output:

```
2b88250 HEAD@{2016-12-02 01:22:55 +0200}: pull ssh://localhost:29418/test-project refs/changes/07/7/1: Fast-forward
b49719d HEAD@{2016-12-02 01:20:46 +0200}: pull ssh://localhost:29418/test-project refs/changes/06/6/1: Fast-forward
1f384f6 HEAD@{2016-12-02 01:19:06 +0200}: clone: from ssh://localhost:29418/test-project
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh maaanannnnnnnn

Answer (score 0):

[How do I check the date and time of the latest `git pull` that was executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993902/how-do-i-check-the-date-and-time-of-the-latest-git-pull-that-was-executed)

This answer has different ways to find the last time a file was edited.

Since you used the osx tag, this will allow you to see the last time that you ran `git pull`:

`stat -f '%m' .git/FETCH_HEAD`

Should print out the time stamp of the last time that FETCH_HEAD was edited, which was the last time you ran `git pull` or `git fetch`.

Sadly, I do not think it is possible to do what you are asking. You can find the last access, last change, **last modified**, and the creation time of a file using `stat`, but I don't think finding the history of "last modified" is possible.

Answer (score 0):

For your current branch you can get the dates for all `git pull` commands you ran by doing the following:

```
$ for i in $(cat .git/logs/refs/heads/<YOUR_BRANCH_NAME_HERE> | grep pull | awk '{print $5}');do date -d@$i; done
```

*Note:* The `awk` arg may change depending on git version. This awk arg works for git version `1.8.3.1`.